# Classifying a critical point using Tangent Space and Hessian Matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I know that the point $x \in \Bbb{R}^3$ is a criticial point of $f|_M$ f and M defined as $$f: \Bbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$$ $$M \subset \Bbb{R}^3, M = g^{-1}(0)$$
$$∂^2f(x) =\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 0\\\ 2 & 1 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix},\nabla g(x) = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\\ 2 \\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
I calculated the tangent space to M in x as
$$T_xM = span\{\begin{pmatrix}2 \\\ -1 \\\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 \\\ 0 \\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\}$$
The example solution I have, calculated a Gram-Matrix using the base of $T_xM$ and the hessian matrix but I wasn't able to understand it. Can you  please help me classify x?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I am not sure if I know how to find the restricted hessian matrix when the $T_xM$ is then span of multiple vectors. I know that matrix if the $T_xM$ was the span of 1 vector v I could just obtain the restricted hessian matrix with <∂^2f(x).v, v>. Can you please tell me how I can  calculate that in case of multiple basis vectors  of $T_xM$?

Comment: When I want to classify the critical point  $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-2)$ of $ f(x,y) = x^2-y$ with constraint $g(x,y) = 4x^2+y^2 = 7$. I find the hessian matrix $$∂f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$and the tangent space to M at that  point $$
T_{(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-2)}M = span\{\begin{bmatrix}-4 \\ -4\sqrt{3}\end{bmatrix}\}$$
But if I calculate the 1x1 matrix you described. $<\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-4 \\ -4\sqrt{3}\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-4 \\ -4\sqrt{3}\end{bmatrix}>=32$ implies that this point  is a minimum but  it  is  in fact a maximum.

Comment: do you have extra information about $f$ and $g$? perhaps an explicit formula?

Comment: No I don't. I believe you can't solve this problem without any extra knowledge. Maybe they meant the given hessian matrix is the hessian matrix of $f(x) - \lambda g(x)$ but they forgot to write it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this question can't be answered without any further knowledge.  If we knew the Hessian Matrix of the  Lagrangian function we could calculate the Gram-Matrix and answer the question accordingly.